# How do i get the length of innerHTML (total characters) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, character, innerhtml

I'm trying to get the length of the characters that I attain from `innerHTML` and it's kind of come down to last resort, but can't seem to find a more efficient way as the data is inside a slider that I'm trying to use to get the lower value and higher value.

```
var lvalue=document.getElementById("lval").innerHTML;
```

then I'm spiting the string in the spaces:

```
var larr=lvalue.split(" ");
```

The `innerHTML` value is something like this "2413dsk 134dfa134".

And when i use `larr[0].length`, I get 1 when I need 7. Is there a solution?

Comment: `larr[0]` refers to the length of the first element of the splitted array..

Comment: Can you post some code? When I type exactly what you wrote here, the answer is 7 (starting with `lvalue = "2413dsk 134dfa134";` instead of `innerHTML`).

Comment: Slider as in HTML5 slider? You may be looking for `document.getElementById('lval').value` rather than `.innerHTML`?

Answer (score 5):

I think it would go something like this:

```
var lvalue = document.getElementById("lval").innerHTML;
var larr = lvalue.split(' ');
var len = 0;

// For each iterates over the index of arrays
for(var i in larr) { 
     len += larr[ i ].length // Acummulate the length of all the strings
}
```

Or alternatively you could count the spaces first and then substract it from the total length.

```
// Some people argue about extending the native objects
// but in this case I think this method is a natural fit.
String.prototype.count = function( character ) {
   var l = 0;
   // `this` refers to the string itself
   for(var c in this) n = this[ c ] === character ? ++n : n;
   return n;
}
```

An then use it like so:

```
var lvalue = document.getElementById("lval").innerHTML;

// Subtract total length minus the number of spaces
var len = lvalue.length - lvalue.count(' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be caused by a preceding or leading space.

Try trimming the extra spaces :

```
var lvalue=document.getElementById("lval").innerHTML.replace(/^\s+/gi,'').replace(/\s+$/gi,'');

var larr=lvalue.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any problem with your code. I run a test here: http://desdegdl.com/lval.html
Probably, you have one or more spaces at the begining of `lval`'s inner HTML.

Answer (score 0):

### If there is someone like me that doesn't want to use JQuery, here is a example in javascript (only)...

### The files

**The html file...**

```
<!-- start body -->
<body>
  <!-- start section -->
    <section id="bar"></section>
  <!-- end section -->
</body>
<!-- end body -->
```

**The javascript file...**

```
/* start - wut element do ya wanna get? */
foo = document.getElementById('bar');
/* end - wut element do ya wanna get? */

/* start function */
function isEmpty(){
  if (foo.innerHTML.length === 0) {
      /* your code here */
  }
}
/* end function */
```

### What I did

**In the HTML**

Quite simple, I just created a section and assigned an ID on it. This ID will be used to call her in our javascript.

**In the JavaScript**

In the var fooI I called the section whose I gave an ID.
After it I created a function that "do something" if the length of a element is equal zero.

### Considerations

It works, but if you have a space or a line break the code will not consider it as "empty"...